# Meaning of “I can ring your napkins out any day, with you tucked in them any day”

Tags: meaning, literature, figurative

I'm reading Arnold Wesker's *The Kitchen* and cannot understand the meaning of:

> I can ring your napkins out any day, with you tucked in them any day.

I understand that it's suggesting beating someone figuratively, but I'm not sure. Could anyone paraphrase it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bad copy of the play. The correct verb is **wring**. One **wrings out** wet cloth items by twisting them to squeeze out some or most of the water or other liquid. The action requires some strength, and the metaphoric use is implying that the speaker is easily capable of overpowering the other person (can wring him out). Also there is a hint of an insult (the listener is no more significant than a wet napkin)

[image]

[Wring (Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/wring)

[The Kitchen (Google Books)](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=X50AyQDaOpcC&pg=PA22&lpg=PA22&dq=%22I%20can%20wring%20your%20napkins%20out%20any%20day,%20with%20you%20tucked%20in%20them%20any%20day.%22&source=bl&ots=czAy7Hkoju&sig=ACfU3U2bbCTJteQ-PYHSX2V7CpJZ4kdXFQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwis6OKBxvzqAhVFoVwKHXjBB3gQ6AEwAXoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22I%20can%20wring%20your%20napkins%20out%20any%20day%2C%20with%20you%20tucked%20in%20them%20any%20day.%22&f=false)